# Extraer un numero en una posición no especifica

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, python-3.7

Tengo un dataframe de 200.000 registros en el que la variable "CONVERSION" toma el valor de alguna de estas 8 cadenas:

```
CONVERSION
'2Play Fono-Internet Destino Mega 400 Sin Capex ANDES'     
'UPS 1P Mega 500 SC $990 Andes'                           
'1Play Solo Internet Destino Mega 200 Con Capex ANDES'    
'Triple Play Destino Mega 200 Sin Capex ANDES'            
'Triple Play Destino Mega 400 Sin Capex ANDES'            
'2Play Cable-Internet Destino Mega 200 Sin Capex ANDES'  
'2Play Cable-Internet Destino Mega 400 Sin Capex ANDES'   
'1Play Solo Internet Destino Mega 400 Sin Capex ANDES'    
'1Play Solo Internet Destino Mega 200 Sin Capex ANDES'
```

Necesito crear una variable "CONSUMO" que contenga el valor numerico que esta inmediatamente despues de la palabra "Mega " en esas cadenas, asi:

```
CONSUMO
400
500
200
200
400
200
400
400
200
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo siguiente asume que **todas las líneas tienen la subcadena** `'Mega'` y que **siempre hay un número** después de ella. En caso contrario, tendrás que poner los controles por si esa cadena no está, recordando que para `str.find()` devuelve `-1` y `re.search` devuelve `None`.

```
>>> line = '2Play Cable-Internet Destino Mega 200 Sin Capex ANDES'
>>> # Opcion 1
>>> start = line.find('Mega')+5
>>> end = line.find(' ', start)
>>> value = line[start:end]
>>> value
'200'
>>>
>>> # Opcion 2
>>> str_list = line.split(' ')
>>> value = str_list[str_list.index('Mega')+1]
>>> value
'200'
>>>
>>> # Opcion 3
>>> import re
>>>
>>> match = re.search('Mega\s([0-9]+)', line)
>>> value = match.group(1)
>>> value
'200'
```

No soy experto en regex y estoy seguro que habrán otras versiones mejores que esa, pero creo que funciona.

Finalmenate te queda meter todas las líneas en un `for` e ir aplicando el algoritmo a cada una para ir extrayendo el valor.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de esta manera:
Cree la funcion extraer_megas

```
def extraer_megas(strings):
    
    mega=None
    for word in strings.split():
        try:
            mega = int(word)
        except:
            pass
    return mega
```

Luego la apliqué sobre la variable buscada, siempre que no tenga Nan como resultado de ninguna observacion:

```
df["CONVERSION"].apply(extraer_megas)
```

Comment: Si bien se obtiene la respuesta.... ten en cuenta que son 200mil registros... no sé si estés trabajando la data con formato `Parquet`, pero ten presente que al usar el bucle `for` en `def extraer_megas(strings)` esto va demandar mucho recurso y va ir lento... te sugiero la `opción 3` propuesta por @aeportugal... con `Pandas` y con el método `str.extract` debería quedarte así: `df['CONVERSION'].str.extract(r'Mega\s([0-9]+)')`

Comment: También en la implementación que has brindado como respuesta, qué pasaría si tuvieras esta cadena `'UPS P Mega 500 SC $ 990 Andes'` se imprimiría `990` y no los `500` que buscas... mi sugerencia si no te sientes comodo con `regex` y deseas mantener la función que has desarrollado... una vez obtengas los valores, los concadenes con `Mega Numero` (patrón) y establezcas una máscara para que corrobores si `Mega Numero` está en la columna `"CONVERSION"` esto se hace necesario por la cantidad de registros que vos ha indicado en su pregunta.